# Extract and print SubString in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Input String:

```
<TagId>ABC</TagId><TagId>PQR</TagId></Tags>
```

> Desired Output:
>   ABC 
>   PQR

Attempt so far:

```js
var myString = "<TagId>ABC</TagId><TagId>PQR</TagId></Tags>";
var count = ((myString.match(new RegExp("<TagId>", "g")) || []).length);
console.log(count); //Getting correct count of 2

for(var i =1;i<=count;i++){
var val = myString.substring(
    myString.lastIndexOf("<TagId>") + 7, 
    myString.lastIndexOf("</TagId>")
);
}
console.log(val);
```

> Actual result from above code snippet: 
>   PQR

Comment: Are you sure the string doesn't have a leading `<Tags>`? That seems a bit strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match non-`>` characters which are followed by `</TagId>`:

```js
const str = '<TagId>ABC</TagId><TagId>PQR</TagId></Tags>';
console.log(str.match(/[^>]+(?=<\/TagId>)/g));
```

`[^>]+(?=<\/TagId>)` means:

- `[^>]+` - Match one or more characters which are not `>`
- `(?=<\/TagId>)` - Such that after the end of the match:

  - `<\/TagId>` - `</TagId>` is found

If you had the leading `<Tags>`, this could be parsed as XML much more elegantly:

```js
const str = '<Tags><TagId>ABC</TagId><TagId>PQR</TagId></Tags>';
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
for (const tagId of doc.querySelectorAll('TagId')) {
  console.log(tagId.textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simply by looping by tagName can retrive the inner text content.

```js
var x =  document.getElementsByTagName("TagId");
for(let i = 0 ; i < x.length; i++) {
  console.log(x[i].textContent)
}
```

```html
<TagId>ABC</TagId><TagId>PQR</TagId></Tags>
```